# Доступ к значению text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Добрый день

Как выдернуть значение, занесенное в текстовое поле?

```
= f.label :right_text, "О компании"
= f.text_field :right_text, :value => "example"

= f.submit :action => [SettingsAboutCompany.right_text = 
                       "ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ПОЛЯ f.text_field :right_text"]
```

Полный код формы

```
= form_for :setting, url: admin_settings_about_company_path do |f|

= f.label :right_text, "О компании"
= f.text_field :right_text, :value => "example"

= f.submit :action => [SettingsAboutCompany.right_text = 
                           "ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ПОЛЯ f.text_field :right_text"]
```

Экшен контроллера

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to admin_settings_about_company_path,
        notice: 'Изменения сохранены' }
    end
end
```

---

**Рабочий код**

Например, с такой записью в БД запишется значение "new_value":

```
= form_for :setting, url: admin_settings_about_company_path do |f|

= f.label :right_text, "О компании"
= f.text_field :right_text, :value => "example"

= f.submit :action => [SettingsAboutCompany.right_text = "new_value"]
```

а нужно записать то, что в text_field

Comment: Выложи полный код формы и контроллер.

Comment: @MAXOPKA добавила код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай так, и посмотри, что выведется при сохранении

```
def update
  abort params.to_yaml
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to admin_settings_about_company_path,
    notice: 'Изменения сохранены' }
  end
end
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавила картинку

Comment: Получается, что `params[:setting]` - хэш, а значение текстового поля в переменной `params[:setting][:right_text]`

Comment: т.е. нужно написать SettingsAboutCompany.right_text = params[:settings][:right_text]  ?

Comment: Я не могу понять, зачем нужна строка `= f.submit :action => [SettingsAboutCompany.right_text = "new_value"]` ? Должно же быть `= f.submit 'Такая-то кнопка'`. А в экшене update перебрать массив `params[:settings]` с индексом, и сохранить каждое поле.

Comment: Спасибо ) то что писать экшн в кнопке  - не лучшее решение, я сразу поняла, но вопрос о том как это сделать элегантнее решила оставить на потом, и в первую очередь разобраться как до значения поля достучаться