# Импорт с помощью .split

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть контроллер tenders

```
class Admin::TendersController < Admin::BaseController
  before_action :set_tender_edit_form, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_tender_decide_form, only: [:decide]
  before_action :require_manager

  def index
    @tenders = Tender.all
  end

  def show
    @user_items = UserItem.all
  end

  def new
    @tender = Tender::AsCreateForm.new
    1.times { @tender.items.build}
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @tender = Tender::AsCreateForm.new(tender_params)
    if @tender.save
      flash[:success] = "Тендер создан. Будут уведомлены #{@tender.recipients_count} пользователей."
      TendersMailer.tender_created(@tender).deliver
      redirect_to admin_tenders_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @tender.update(tender_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Тендер отредактирован.'
      redirect_to admin_tender_path(@tender)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @tender.destroy
    flash[:success] = 'Тендер удален.'
    TendersMailer.tender_destroyed(@tender).deliver
    redirect_to admin_tenders_url
  end

  def decide
    if @tender.update(choose_winner_params)
      flash[:success] = "Тендер завершен. #{@tender.sended_mails} уведомлений отправлено поставщикам"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render 'show'
    end
  end

  def close_without_winner
    @tender = Tender.find(params[:id]).becomes(Tender::AsCloseWithoutWinner)
    if @tender.save
      flash[:success] = "Тендер завершен. #{@tender.sended_mails} уведомлений отправлено поставщикам"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render 'show'
    end
  end

  def start_second_stage
    @tender = Tender.find(params[:id]).becomes(Tender::AsStartSecondStage)
    if @tender.save
      flash[:success] = "Начат второй этап. #{@tender.sended_mails} уведомлений отправлено поставщикам"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render 'show'
    end
  end

  private
    def set_tender_edit_form
      @tender = Tender.find(params[:id]).becomes(Tender::AsEditForm)
    end

    def set_tender_decide_form
      @tender = Tender.find(params[:id]).becomes(Tender::AsChooseWinnerForm)
    end

    def tender_params
      params.require(:tender).permit(
        :name,
        :status_id,
        :uslovie,
        :dopuslovie,
        :data_start,
        :data_end,
        :fls,
        :manager_id,
        :etap,
        items_attributes: [:id, :name, :quantity, :measure_unit, :gost, :description, :_destroy, :winner_id],
        category_ids: []
      )
    end

    def choose_winner_params
      params.require(:tender).permit(
        items_attributes: [:id, :winner_id],
      )
    end
end
```

Есть вьюха

```
<%= nested_form_for @tender, url: @tender.new_record? ? admin_tenders_path : admin_tender_path(@tender), as: :tender do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', target: @tender %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <%= title %>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :name, 'Заголовок' %>
                  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <% if f.object.new_record? %>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <%= f.label :data_start, 'Дата начала' %>
                      <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <%= f.text_field :data_start, class: 'form-control' %>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <%= f.label :data_end, 'Дата окончания' %>
                      <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                        <%= f.text_field :data_end, class: 'form-control' %>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :manager_id, 'Менеджер' %>
                  <% if current_manager.admin? %>
                      <%= f.collection_select(:manager_id, Manager.all, :id, :name, {:prompt=>true}, {:class=>'form-control'}) %>
                  <% else %>
                      <%= current_manager.name %>
                      <%= f.hidden_field :manager_id, :value => @current_manager.id %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :uslovie, 'Условия тендера' %>
                  <%= f.text_area :uslovie, rows: '4', class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :dopuslovie, 'Дополнительно' %>
                  <%= f.text_area :dopuslovie, rows: '4', class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :fls, 'Прикрепить файл' %>
                  <%= f.file_field :fls %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h1>Категории тендеров</h1>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <p class="help-block">От категории зависит группа рассылки приглашений для поставщиков</p>
                  <%= f.label :categories, 'Категории' %>
                  <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) do |b| %>
                      <% b.label(class: 'checkbox') { b.check_box + ' ' + b.text }  %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2 class="sub-header">Добавить позиции</h2>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <%= f.fields_for :items do |items_form| %>
                      <%= render 'item_fields', :f => items_form %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
                <%= f.link_to_add 'Добавить', :items, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-success' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <%= f.submit (f.object.new_record? ? 'Создать' : 'Обновить'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Я хочу сделать следующее. Хочу во вьюхе new сделать что-то типа

```
<%= form_tag(new_admin_tender_path, method: "GET") do %>
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= text_area_tag(:data) %>
        </div>
        <%= submit_tag("Импорт") %>
    </form>
<% end %>
```

И в контролере сделать примерно следующее

```
rows = data.split("\n")
    rows.each do |row|
      vals = row.split("\t")
      item = Item.new(
        name: vals[0],
        quantity: vals[1],  
        measure_unit: vals[2],
        gost: vals[3],
        description: vals[4]    
      )
      @tenders.items << item
    end
```

То есть хочу в `text_area_tag` ввести данные, нажать кнопку импорт, и у меня бы обновлялась страница и все эти данные с `text_area_tag` отсплителись и попали бы в нужные мне поля, но никак не могу домучить данный вопрос.

**Обновление**

я думал что мне нужно сделать в контроллере так

```
def new
    rows = data.split("\n")
    rows.each do |row|
      vals = row.split("\t")
      item = Item.new(
        name: vals[0],
        quantity: vals[1],  
        measure_unit: vals[2],
          gost: vals[3],
          description: vals[4]      
      )
      @tenders.items << item
    end
    @tender = Tender::AsCreateForm.new
    1.times { @tender.items.build}
  end
```

То получаю

> undefined local variable or metjod 'data' for controller

**Обновление 2**

```
def new
data = params[:data]
unless data.nil?
    rows = data.split("\n")
    rows.each do |row|
      vals = row.split("\t")
      item = Item.new(
        name: vals[0],
        quantity: vals[1],  
        measure_unit: vals[2],
          gost: vals[3],
          description: vals[4]      
      )
      @tenders.items << item
    end
end
    @tender = Tender::AsCreateForm.new
    1.times { @tender.items.build}
  end
```

Прошло, но теперь поругалось на

> undefined method items for nil

В строке

```
@tenders.items << item
```

Comment: Что конкретно не получается? Ошибка где-то?

Comment: я не знаю как мне то что я введу в text_area_tag запихнуть в data из этой строки rows = data.split("\n")

Comment: Ни хрена не понял

Comment: Для того, чтобы на ваши вопросы было проще ответить, стоит ознакомиться с руководством [Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял вопрос звучит так: "Где искать отправленные данные с формы в экшене контроллера?"

Все данные, которые передаются с помощью форм в экшен контроллера, можно получить из хэша `params`.

Если вы не знаете структуру передаваемых данных, то выполните в экшене:

```
abort params.to_s
```

или

```
abort params.to_yaml
```

Выполнение экшена прервется, выдав сообщение, содержащее переданные данные. 
В общем случае, содержимое поля `data`, в экшене контроллера, можно получить так:

```
data = params[:data]
```

P.S. [Доступ к значению text_field](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/441932/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-text-field) - тут нечто подобное спрашивали.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо заработало

```
def new
        data = params[:data]
        @tender = Tender::AsCreateForm.new
        1.times { @tender.items.build}
        unless data.nil?
            rows = data.split("\n")
            rows.each do |row|
                vals = row.split("\t")
                item = Item.new(
                    name: vals[0],
                    quantity: vals[1],  
                    measure_unit: vals[2],
                    gost: vals[3],
                    description: vals[4]      
                  )
                  @tender.items << item
            end
        end   
    end
```